# How to find selection is continue are / continue using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I Need a Excel VBA Code to find if my selection is continue then i need msg box TRUE if not continue it should be false

Comment: `MsgBox ActiveCell.Value = "Continue"`? What is the selection?

Comment: yes  i need code if selection is Continue it should show true

Comment: *What* is the selection - a cell, a userform, what exactly?

Comment: its a range Example: if range(A1:A4).select it should be true if Range("A1") and range(b3) then false

Comment: Do you mean if the selection is contiguous or if it has multiple areas?

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need to `Select` or work with the `Selection`, but if you are looking for whether the `Selection` is contiguous cells, or has multiple areas, then maybe like this:

```
Sub Test()
    If TypeOf Selection Is Excel.Range Then
        MsgBox Selection.Areas.Count = 1
    End If
End Sub
```